# Authenticate to GMail without interaction

Tags: authentication, oauth, gmail, google-signin

I have implemented Google's various client libraries but when the app first connects to GMail it opens the Google authorisation dialog or prints the URL to the dialog in the logs and halts.

I need my service to have zero user interaction and cannot find anything on the Google docs to provide information on how to log in to GMail without interaction.

Please advise

Comment: They'll have to do it at least the first time. After that, see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#authorizing_with_stored_credentials; pay particular attention to the bit about the "refresh token".

Comment: @ceejayoz Is there no service-to-service approach that bypasses user interaction?
I admit I can't find anything to suggest there is but it just seems... odd!

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail says "Choosing a third-party email service to use", so it's pretty clear they're not all that interested in letting you do that.